# Custom input component ignores update from method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, binding, vue-component

I did a custom input component, it works correctly but there is a problem: when i try to update its value from a method the model is updated but the input value still there.

This is my component:
https://codepen.io/ken-ramirez/pen/JgyKad

```js
const BasicInput = {
  template: '<input v-model="content" @input="handleInput" />',
  prop: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      content: this.value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput (e) {
      this.$emit('input', this.content)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { name: '' },
  components: { BasicInput },
  methods: {
    restart() {
      this.name = ''
    }
  }
})
```

You can press on restart button to see what i mean.

Comment: You have a mistake in your code: `props`, not `prop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code: `props`, not `prop`.

But this is not enough, also you need to update your `content` manually, it's not reactive with `value` prop. Everything declared inside `data` is not reactive with its initial values.

```js
const BasicInput = {
  template: '<input v-model="content" @input="handleInput" />',
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      content: this.value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput (e) {
      this.$emit('input', this.content)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      this.content = val;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @NikitaK mentioned in his answer you're making a typo , you should write `props` instead of `prop`, but i want to give a shorter solution without using `watcher` property only with this code `@input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)"`

**Full example**

```js
const BasicInput = {
  template: `<input :value="value" @input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)" />`,
  props: ['value']

}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
  return{
     name: ''
  }},
  components: { BasicInput },
  methods: {
    restart() {
      this.name = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <basic-input v-model="name"></basic-input>
  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong> {{ name }}
  </p>
  <button @click="restart">restart</button>
</div>
```